# Convert a flat model into a structured one

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Basically, I want to be able to convert something like

```
{
    "name": "",
    "street_address": "",
    "city": ""
}
```

into this

```
{
    "name": "",
    "address" : {
        "street_address": "",
        "city": ""
    }
}
```

while still retaining a model that would look like this

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    street_address = models.CharField()
    city = models.CharField()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you post `view` ?

Comment: I'm just using viewsets.ModelViewSet and setting the queryset and serializer_class attributes.

Comment: so modify `serializer.data` as your wish in `JsonResponse`

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this approach if what @Martol1ni suggests won't work out.

Answer (score 1):

Override the `to_representation()` method to alter the serialization.

```
class ModelASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = ('name', 'street_address', 'city')


    def to_representation(self, instance):
        x = super(ModelASerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        desired_response = {}
        desired_response['name'] = x['name']
        desired_response['address'] = {'street_address': x['street_address'],
                                       'city': x['city']}
        return desired_response
```

Answer (score 0):

This is about serializers.

```
class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = ('street_address', 'city')

class ModelASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    address = AddressSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = ('name', 'address')
```

`ModelASerializer` would then yield;

```
{
    "name": "",
    "address": {
        "street_address": "",
        "city": ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. I tried this and POST works (have yet to try PUT). The problem now is that GET throws an AttributeError. In the case above, I'll say 'ModelA' object has no attribute 'address'.